# How does one distinguish between file and content URIs when accessing sound assets in the Android app

Tags: android, crash, android-notifications, android-fileprovider

I am a beginner Android engineer. We are observing multiple crashes related to lack of access to the sound assets, and I want to know how to best access the private sound files. Some of the stack traces observed are as follows:

```
Caused by android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Girl%20on%20fire.mp4 exposed beyond app through Notification.sound
       at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed + 1799(StrictMode.java:1799)
       at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed + 2354(Uri.java:2354)
       at android.app.NotificationManager.notifyAsUser + 303(NotificationManager.java:303)
       at android.app.NotificationManager.notify + 287(NotificationManager.java:287)
       at android.app.NotificationManager.notify + 271(NotificationManager.java:271)
```

and

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Uid 10141 does not have permission to uri 0 @ content://media/external/audio/media/35413
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1718(Parcel.java:1718)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException + 1671(Parcel.java:1671)
       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.grantUriPermission + 4906(ActivityManagerProxy.java:4906)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.grantUriPermission + 1664(ContextImpl.java:1664)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.grantUriPermission + 722(ContextWrapper.java:722)
```

In both of these cases, the sound file is not accessible to the app when creating a notification. I have read the following articles with respect to setting file providers. I am guessing that the external storage refers to the file system on the device, but I don't know if this is right.

1. https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/FileProvider
2. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage
3. https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en (regarding FileUriExposedException)

My question is as follows:

1. I discovered that there are two URIs, namely the one that starts with `file://`, and `content://`. If the URI string starts with `file://`, then I could use the third link to convert it to that of content URI. What would I need to do if the file URI already starts with `content://`?

This is my current logic:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = getBuilder(); // Helper function to initialize the builder
String defaultRingTone = "android.resource://" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "/" + R.raw.default;
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(); // Returns an instance of shared preference.
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(sharedPreferences.getString(PREF_NOTIFICATIONS_TONE,
        DEFAULT_TONE));  // PREF_NOTIFICATIONS_TONE points to the string based path.
context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), soundUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
builder.setSound(soundUri);


. . . . Use the NotificationManager to render the notification . . .
```

**DESIRED BEHAVIOUR**

I want the notification to be rendered with sound and not crash.

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/09/07/notifications-sounds-android-7p0-aggravation.html

Comment: @CommonsWare I have been setting read permissions like this `context.grantUriPermission(context.getPackageName(), soundUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`. Isn't this correct?

Comment: @CommonsWare When we are required to convert path starting with `file://` to `content://`, we can use `FileProvider#getUriForFile` to do the conversion. Do we still do it when the path is a `content://` path?

Comment: "Isn't this correct?" -- that would grant your app the right to read your own content. That is not your problem. Your problem is that the system UI lacks the right to read your content. "Do we still do it when the path is a content:// path?" -- no. However, there is no safe and stable way to grant the system UI the rights to any secured `content://` `Uri`, whether it is your own (e.g., `FileProvider`) or one from a third party (such as your `content://media/external/audio` one).

Comment: @CommonsWare I would still need to implement the FileProvider apis, right?

Comment: You don't know where the files are for a `content://media/external/audio` `Uri`. Use `FileProvider` for files that you manage.

Comment: @CommonsWare one last question if you don't mind. I would need to set the permissions first before setting the sound, right? My proposed solution is 

`Uri uri = notificationHelper.getSoundUri(soundFile);`

`context.grantUriPermission("com.android.systemui", uri, 
      Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);`

`builder.setSound(uri);`

Comment: You would need to grant the permission before showing the notification. A `NotificationCompat.Builder` is simply assembling a data structure (`Notification`) that will be sent via IPC to the system to display via `show()` on `NotificationManager`. So long as you try granting the permission before `show()` you should be OK (or at least as OK as a blind permission grant like this can be). Whether it is before or after `setSound()` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder` should not matter.